# Get an older version of your model back Anylogic

Tags: backup, anylogic

I've a question, I made some change in my model and probably did something wrong, but now every time I open my model, it crashes when I want to open something and I need to close anylogic.. So now I want to open an older version of the model, so that I can work further without having to use a backup of one week ago, is anylogic automaticaly saving some older copies of my model or not? If so where can i find these older versions.

Or is there a way to solve this problem. I deleted the type of the arraylist LiftpleinenPeds collection, and now everytime I click on the collection to change this, the whole anylogic crashes. I only need to change it in the main java to add node as shown in the image, but I am not able to modify something there?

[image]

Comment: Check the folder where alp file is located. See if you have something saved as backup there

Comment: @Yashar I already did, it is not, I know where the problem is, I can see it in the main java, but is there a way to solve it? I will ad it in the original post.

Comment: It is already solved! I deleted this part with notepad and then opened it with anylogic, it seems to work fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the AnyLogic file the '.alp' file inside any text editor. You can make your changes there (but be careful) and rather make a backup before you do this.

You can literally build your entire model in *text mode* if you want to ;-)

Comment: If it is loaded in fine in anylogic (after you delete this part) and the collection is gone, is there a chance I will get an error later for deleting it by hand or is it now probably solved?

Comment: It is probably solved now - the AnyLogic compiled was supposed to catch this before creating the model for you and rather give you a warning like the model file is corrupt. Do you mind sending the corrupt file to support for them to review if they can perhaps handle it (even fix it) upon load

Comment: I will do this! thanks